# rake aborted! no such file to load -- sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rake, rails-postgresql

I've set up a new rails3 app and my gemfile is below

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'pg'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

as seen from the Gemfile, I intend on using `postgresql` as the database and not the default `sqllite3`.  however, when I tried doing rake db:create or rake db:migrate for the first time, it keeps giving me error `rake aborted! no such file to load -- sqllite3`

There was a file in `db/development.sqllite` which I deleted after I got this error...thinking that it will help. but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /config/database.yml file

You probably have it still set to connect to a sqlite3 database (the default)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error was resolved by installing the libsqlite3-ruby1.9.1 library from aptitude.

RoR 3.1, Ruby1.9.2

Comment: hi Ryanmt, would you be able to give me detail command to do this? i am using mac.. thanks :)

Comment: Love to... But I don't use a mac.  The command in Ubuntu would be `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-ruby1.9.1`.  Hope that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

download that below:
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070701.zip
upzipped and dropped in your/ruby/path/lib(eg.c:\ruby192)